# Removing null values from objects in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, knockout.js, null

I am trying to read data from a `Mysql` Database and bring it to my `Knockout` powered UI.

So far, everything's fine.
My problem is some fields in the database have got "null" values, and so they also show up on my UI.

So the question is: **How can I replace these null values, saved as parameters in Objects, which are saved in an array?**

Any idea?

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: output.innerHTML = myArr[3].propA != null ? myArr[3].propA : "";

Comment: Can you show us your code so we can make changes to solve your issue?  Good questions asking for code nearly always include relevant portions of your current code.

Answer (score 0):

To remove (I guess that's what you mean by "replace") a property (I guess that's what you mean by "parameter") from an object you have to use the `delete` operator, like so:

```
> test = {a: null, b: "b"}
{ a: null, b: 'b' }
> delete test.a
true
> test
{ b: 'b' }
```